# Android Fragment support , java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Fragment(Context,AttributeSet)

Tags: android, android-annotations, android-support-library

I try to use fragments with AndroidAnnotations and maven.
It worked with Android 4.0+ , but then I tried to make it work with Android 2.3.3 and I had  to use the support-v4 maven library:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.android</groupId>
    <artifactId>support-v4</artifactId>
    <version>r7</version>
</dependency>
```

My fragment is defined as:

```
<android.support.v4.app.Fragment android:id="@+id/myFragment"
                                 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                 class="com.bla.HeaderFragment_"/>
```

and My Activity extends FragmentActivity

I get this exception when I run the app:

.....

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #7: Error inflating class android.support.v4.app.Fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:508)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:570)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:623)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:408)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:207)
at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1657)
at com.tagonsoft.codecamp.MainActivity_.setContentView(MainActivity_.java:46)
at com.tagonsoft.codecamp.MainActivity_.onCreate(MainActivity_.java:31)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
... 11 more

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Fragment(Context,AttributeSet)
at java.lang.Class.getMatchingConstructor(Class.java:643)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:472)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:480)
... 22 more
```

Any idea why?

Comment: Does your fragment have an empty constructor?

Comment: no, I try to use it with AndroidAnnotations like here https://github.com/excilys/androidannotations/wiki/Enhance-Fragments

Comment: Use the `fragment` tag instead of `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `<fragment>` tag and `name` attribute for class name. Also, you've used class name as `com.bla.HeaderFragment_` , seems like a typo.

```
<fragment android:id="@+id/myFragment"
          android:name="com.bla.HeaderFragment_"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                                 />
```

More Examples [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating).

Comment: It appears to be working with both _android:name_ and _class_. The documentation from the support library mentions _class_ http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#Layout . The final underscore is for the class generated by AndroidAnnotations.

Comment: I can't find right now but, I've read about this somewhere, 'name' will work for both old and new API.